# How to show images on zend framewrok from index view?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

I am new to zend framewrok. I am trying to show an image from index view. Below is my code:

```
<?php         
echo "Student List";
//$this->headTitle($this->title);
?>
<p><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index', 
        'action'=>'add'));?>">Add new student</a></p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Photo</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($this->students as $student) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($student->name);?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($student->email);?></td>
    <td><img src='opt/lampp/htdocs/framework/zf-tutorial/project.png' alt='sdfsd'></td>
    <td>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index', 
            'action'=>'edit', 'id'=>$student->id));?>">Edit</a>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index', 
            'action'=>'delete', 'id'=>$student->id));?>">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

It only show the alt text not the image. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the default folder structure try this:

Create an Folder `images`. Put your image `project.png` inside of you `public` folder (public/images/project.png).

In your view Script use the baseUrl Viewhelper:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl() . '/images/project.png' ?>" alt='sdfsd'/>
```

Comment: I used $fileName = $upload->getFileName('photo'); $fileName = basename($fileName); to get the file name can you say how can I rename the file name before receiving it.

Comment: Check Zend Filter Rename http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.file.transfer.filters.html#zend.file.transfer.filters.rename

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access images folder contents in PHP code than use this

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/images/project.png" />
```

and if you want to access images in your javascript than write below code in your `layout.phtml`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var config = {baseUrl: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>'};
   </script>
```

now you can access images folder contents  like this

```
<img src="'+config.baseUrl+'/images/project.png" />
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to get the only file name of uploaded file. Now I am using getFileName() which returns whole path

Comment: getFileName($file = null, $path = true):

Comment: $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$fileName = $upload->getFileName('file');
can you adjust mycode to get the filename

Comment: $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
$upload->receive();

// Returns the file names from all files
$names = $upload->getFileName();

// Returns the file names from the 'foo' form element
$names = $upload->getFileName('foo');

Comment: I used 
$fileName = $upload->getFileName('photo'); 
$fileName = basename($fileName);
to get the file name can you say how can I rename the file name before receiving it.

Comment: why you are using basename() ?? and can you please paste result of  echo "<pre>"; print_r($fileName); echo "</pre>";

Comment: /opt/lampp/htdocs/framework/zf-tutorial/public/images/abf.png 
this is the output of print_r($fineName)

Comment: @user1939096 remove the basename() and than u can get abf.png